# Socket Programming on Android

Tags: android, sockets

I have written a simple snippet of code, that connects to a server, that is a non-Android device. I provide the IP and the port number to this, via an Edit Text, and then it gets connected to the network. But everytime, I click connect, the application stops by itself. Can anyone help me with what the error is ?

Code:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;




import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SocketClient extends Activity {

 boolean shouldRun = false;
 TextView textResponse;
 EditText editTextAddress, editTextPort; 
 Button buttonConnect, buttonClear;
 private final Context context = this;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.client);

  editTextAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);
  editTextPort = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.port);
  buttonConnect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.connect);
  buttonClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);

  buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(buttonConnectOnClickListener);

  buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
//    textResponse.setText("");
   }});
 }

 OnClickListener buttonConnectOnClickListener = 
   new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String destAddress = editTextAddress.getText().toString();
        String destPort = editTextPort.getText().toString();
        if (destAddress!=null && destPort!=null){
       shouldRun = true;
       MyClientTask myClientTask = new MyClientTask(
       editTextAddress.getText().toString(),
       Integer.parseInt(editTextPort.getText().toString()));
        myClientTask.execute();
        } else
        {
            ShowDialog("Please enter a valid ip address and port");
        }

    }};

 public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  String dstAddress;
  int dstPort;
  String response = "";

  MyClientTask(String addr, int port){
   dstAddress = addr;
   dstPort = port;
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

   Socket socket = null;

   try {
    socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = 
                  new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    int bytesRead;
    ShowDialog("Connection Successful");
    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

    /*
     * notice:
     * inputStream.read() will block if no data return
     */
             while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                 byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                 response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
             }
   } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
    ShowDialog("Connection Unsuccessful");

   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
   }finally{
    if(socket != null){
     try {
      socket.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
   }
   return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   textResponse.setText(response);
   super.onPostExecute(result);
  }

 }

public void ShowDialog(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    dialog.setTitle(string);

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById (R.id.dialogButtonOK);

    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}

}
```

EDIT:
Error is still persisting, and the Log Cat has been updated. Please check it!

```
07-02 14:23:42.195: E/AndroidRuntime(31810):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
07-02 14:26:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(401): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-02 14:26:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(401): Process: com.example.socketserverclient, PID: 401
07-02 14:26:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(401): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-02 14:26:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
07-02 14:26:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
07-02 14:26:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
07-02 14:26:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
07-02 14:26:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-02 14:26:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-02 14:26:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-02 14:26:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-02 14:26:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(401): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
07-02 14:26:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
07-02 14:26:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
07-02 14:26:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:109)
07-02 14:26:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:133)
07-02 14:26:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at com.example.socketserverclient.SocketClient.ShowDialog(SocketClient.java:142)
07-02 14:26:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at com.example.socketserverclient.SocketClient$MyClientTask.doInBackground(SocketClient.java:118)
07-02 14:26:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at com.example.socketserverclient.SocketClient$MyClientTask.doInBackground(SocketClient.java:1)
07-02 14:26:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-02 14:26:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-02 14:26:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  ... 4 more
```

Comment: So in SocketClient.java what code is at line number 133 ?

Comment: `super.onPostExecute(result)`

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized `TextView textResponse` like `(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewID);` something and you are setting `setText("")` to it.  I can't found this in your code. So , I think this is missing.

Comment: Plus, in the same, the layout for the client server, even though I have added that, when there is nothing entered in the box for the ip address and the port number, show me a dialog box, but it's not working. Can you help in that matter ?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `ShowDialog` function in main thread that's why you getting error.

```
ShowDialog("Connection Successful");
```

or

```
ShowDialog("Connection Unsuccessful");
```

You have to use this `onPostExecute`.

```
 Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Generally above error shown when we are updating ui on main thread.

Comment: No respite. I tried doing the above thing that you suggested!

Comment: @BumbleBee check updated answer and u cnt update UI element on doInBackground method

Comment: I removed all `UI` steps from the code. Wait, I am editing the question again, with the new code altogether. The new logcat too! Please review it once!

Comment: Is there a difference between searching for a socket via internet, and searching a socket on the common wifi ?
The application that I have built seems to work fine, when connected to internet, but does not support connection, when not connected to internet!

Comment: seriously not understand you asking a question above different but now asking question different now im puzzle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56638/discussion-between-bumblebee-and-golu).